# Another Party is not receiving transaction even after setting the Party

Tags: corda

I have set the other party in the flow. Still not receiving the transaction.

```
   val auth = CordaX500Name.parse("O=TaxAuthority,L=Paris,C=FR")
    val party1 = rpcOps.wellKnownPartyFromX500Name(auth)
            ?: return Response.status(BAD_REQUEST).entity("Party named $auth cannot be found.\n").build()
```

in exampleAPI and in the flow

```
        val taxAuthority : Set<Party> = setOf(taxauthority)
        progressTracker.currentStep = FINALISING_TRANSACTION
        val signedtx : SignedTransaction = subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx,taxAuthority,FINALISING_TRANSACTION.childProgressTracker()))
```

Comment: Have you set the tax authority as a participant on the state?

Comment: No haven't done that.

Comment: The tax authority won't store the state in its vault if it's not a participant on the state.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by not correctly registering the parties as participants in the State.

In Corda, you can freely share the signedTransaction with whoever you want in the network, and the party who got the signedTransaction will record the tx. However, only the participants of the output state will record the actual output state that the transaction carries.

The session that you passed in the `FinalityFlow` is just an observer session.